# Using Ajax and Dialog Widget

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a Dialog Widget for generate a popup with this code in my index.php:

```
<button class="btn btn btn-info openObs">Deixar observação</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

and

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $(".openObs").click(function() {
          $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

so far no problem, but i have a ajax code that generate for me this buttons in a table in other archive and echoes the result back in my index.php in a result div:

```
 $return .= "$tabela";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $data = str_replace('-', '/', $row['consulta_data']);
                  $data =  date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));
            $return .= "<tr>";
            $return .= "<td>" .$row['consulta_idConsulta']."</td>";
            $id = $row['documento_id'];
            $return .= "<td>" .$data. "</td>";
            $return .= "<td>" .$row['consulta_hora']. "</td>";
            $return .= "<td>" .$row['consulta_desc']. "</td>";
            $return .= "<td>" .$row['profissional_nome']. "</td>";
            $return .= "<td>" . "<button class=\"btn btn btn-info openObs\">Deixar observação</button></td>";
            $return .= "</tr>";

          }

          echo $return .=" </tbody>
              </table>";
```

The problem is, when i click on the button generated by ajax nothing happens but if I put a button manually like up there works normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the button is generated. To avoid this, you need to use on()
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(body).on('click', '.openObs', function(){

});
```

Here is the [js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mksh4eu3/14/) for you. You can test it by enabling and disable individual function.

Make sure that the $(body) is not an element that is appended on later. So it can be $('.container'), as long as it is not javascript generated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that when you are binding the click function for dialog, the button you are creating with ajax is not present in the DOM yet , hence no binding will be done on the buttons created by ajax after your binding. To achieve this functionality, a simple way is to bind the same function again after you created the button with ajax. This will solve the issue.